# Adjust image opacity with createImage in Java

Tags: java, canvas, applet

Is it possible to adjust the alpha of an image when drawing it to a canvas like so?

```
public void drawImg(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
}
```

"img" is an Image object declared to a local file. If this is not possible, is it possible to change the alpha of "img" without actually altering the source file? Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your image already has alpha data associated with it, you should just be able to draw it directly.  You may have to do a `setOpaque(true)` for the object that you are drawing so that the alpha will show up properly.(this will only work for Swing components, you shouldn't be using the `Canvas` from AWT unless you absolutely have to).

You can also modify the image in-memory, as long as you don't write the image back to disk it won't be permanently changed.  If you're loading the image through `ImageIO.read()` you get back a `BufferedImage`, which you can modify as much as you want.

Answer (score 1):

This is a easy and short most developers using java code for image fade.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.RescaleOp;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

/**
 *
 * @author ADMIN
 */
public class ImageFade extends JFrame {

    ImageFade() {
        setLayout(null);

        JLabel l = new JLabel();
        l.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 96);
        add(l);

        Thread tp = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int amp = 0; amp <= 500; amp++) {
                    try {
                        sleep(1);
                        try {
                            BufferedImage bim = ImageIO.read(new File("src/image/fade/image.png"));
                            BufferedImage nbim = new BufferedImage(bim.getWidth(), bim.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                            Graphics2D createGraphics = nbim.createGraphics();
                            createGraphics.drawImage(bim, null, 0, 0);
                            RescaleOp r = new RescaleOp(new float[]{1f, 1f, 1f, (float) amp / 500}, new float[]{0, 0, 0, 0}, null);
                            BufferedImage filter = r.filter(nbim, null);
                            l.setIcon(new ImageIcon(filter));
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            System.err.println(ex);
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        tp.start();

        setUndecorated(true);
        setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        setSize(100, 96);
        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ImageFade fr = new ImageFade();
    }
}
```

in this code you can see a thread code. in the thread this image will fade in.

the used image is stack overflow web page's logo image.

only by shown code the image will fade in.

```
Thread tp = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int amp = 0; amp <= 500; amp++) {
            try {
                sleep(1);
                try {
                    BufferedImage bim = ImageIO.read(new File("src/image/fade/image.png"));
                    BufferedImage nbim = new BufferedImage(bim.getWidth(), bim.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                    Graphics2D createGraphics = nbim.createGraphics();
                    createGraphics.drawImage(bim, null, 0, 0);
                    RescaleOp r = new RescaleOp(new float[]{1f, 1f, 1f, (float) amp / 500}, new float[]{0, 0, 0, 0}, null);
                    BufferedImage filter = r.filter(nbim, null);
                    l.setIcon(new ImageIcon(filter));
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                      System.err.println(ex);
                  }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
        }
    }
};
tp.start();
```

This code is very simple to use.

This is not from any book, internet or etc. It is developed by me.

A normal image is not able to change alpha. By code : `BufferedImage nbim = new BufferedImage(bim.getWidth(), bim.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);` the image will convert to ARGB - Alpha, Red, Green, Blue (R,G,B,A) image.

So you can change the alpha of a image.